# Why does my DataFrame pass in and out of a function as a DataFrame and then somehow become a tuple back in the next line of code?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe that passes into a function. The function splits one to many columns into two columns each, (Date Time Group fields into a Date column and a Time column) then passes the dataframe back out. At that point back in the code, it becomes a tuple and screws up the next line of code. I want it to stay a dataframe and don't understand why it changed types all of a sudden.

I have searched Stack Overflow as well as Google. Anyone have any ideas without seeing my lines of code? My code is currently on a different network.

I expect my variable type to be pandas dataframe but it changes to tuple somehow. I have the variable being assigned to the function call using the same variable.

```
datetimesplitdf = DTG_split(datetimesplitdf)
```

And then at the next line back in the code datetimesplitdf is a tuple and even typing:

```
datetimesplitdf = pd.DataFrame(list(datetimesplitdf))
```

isn't working. Thank you...

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the function in question, there really isn't a good way to know what's happening or how to help. That's why the site instructions ask for a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: " At that point back in the code, it becomes a tuple and screws up the next line of code. I want it to stay a dataframe and don't understand why it changed types all of a sudden." Python won't magically turn things into tuple objects. If your function returns a tuple object, is because whoever wrote that function wrote it to return a tuple. An important thing to note, Python variables *do not have types*.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I think I figured it out. Apologies for the fire drill. I ended up needing to pass 2 arguments in AND out of the function so I changed my code from the question, but only had one variable and I assume it was putting both return objects into the single variable. ie, datetimesplitdf = DTG_split(datetimesplitdf, dtg_columns). Once I added a 2nd variable to correspond to the two arguments, it worked fine. datetimesplitdf, dtgcols = DTG_split(datetimesplitdf, dtg_columns). I learned something! :)

Comment: The issue here isn't the arguments, is that you wrote `DTG_split` to return a `tuple` object. Python functions return only a single object, but if you `return a, b` that is simply returning the tuple `(a, b)`